# Informations about a request for Savon Gem , WSDL and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, ruby-on-rails-3.1, wsdl

**I solved my problem, but i still can't understand why there was this ** problem.**

Little explanation : I have to make a call to SOAP server, with some params.

Here is the definition from the wsdl webservice :

```
Method : "lanceDecodage"
 Jeton: xsd:string
 ID_JOB: xsd:string
 Priorite: xsd:int
```

I wanted to do this like this :

```
@response_second = Savon.client(server).request(:lanceDecodage) do
      soap.body =  {
       :jeton => "ABCDEF"
       :ID_JOB => "123"
       :Priorite => 456
      }
    end
```

But the server say me i didn't specified the "Priorite" params.

So this ugly request did the trick :

```
 @response_second = Savon.client(server).request(:lanceDecodage) do
          soap.body =  
            '<Jeton>ABCDEF</Jeton><ID_JOB>' + sound.id_job.to_s + '</ID_JOB><Priorite xsi:type="xsd:int">456</Priorite>'
        end
```

What was the problem with the 'xsi:type="xsd:int"' ? Did we have to specify the type for Integer? Is there a problem on the WebService?

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Can you post the Savon log where it sends the SOAP request?

Comment: Yes, i can, but how to do this?

Comment: You want the response from the soap server? if not, what file do you need?

Comment: To enable debugging in Savon, you need to enable it through config/initializers/savon_config.rb
`config.log = true`. Once you do this, run your code and then post the debug information in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a really good answer, but apparently the problem is from the shitty SOAP service... 
Thank's for your responses